# TextToSpeech with GCM not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, text-to-speech

I am merging TextToSpeech into GCM gcmquickstart example.
After receiving the message from google server, i try to use tts speaking them.
tts always goes to ondestroy before speaking.
but if using debug mode, tts can work as normal.
The code is as follows:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
private TextToSpeech tts;
private String ttsMessage;

public void onInit(int code) {
    if (code == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        if (tts != null) {

            if (Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode(ttsMessage)) {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            } else {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.CHINESE);
            }

            tts.speak(ttsMessage, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            Log.d(TAG, "tts speak!!!");
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "tts initialized!!!");
    } else {
        tts = null;
    }
}

public void onDestroy() {
    //Close the Text to Speech Library
    if(tts != null) {

        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
        Log.d(TAG, "TTS Destroyed");
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    ttsMessage = message;
    if (tts == null) {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }
}
// [END receive_message]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, not the best, but it works.

Run an infinite loop inside onMessageReceived, this makes tts not being destroyed.
When tts finishs its work, jump out the loop.

```
    public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private String ttsMessage;
    private boolean keepAlive = true;

    @Override
    public void onInit(int code) {
        if (code == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            if (tts != null) {

                if (Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode(ttsMessage)) {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                } else {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.CHINESE);
                }


                tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                        keepAlive = false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                    }
                });
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"messageID");
                tts.speak(ttsMessage, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "tts speak!!!");
        } else {
            tts = null;
            keepAlive = false;
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
    //Close the Text to Speech Library
    if(tts != null) {

        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
        Log.d(TAG, "TTS Destroyed");
    }
    super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    ttsMessage = message;
    if (tts == null) {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }
        keepAlive = true;

        while (keepAlive) {
            Log.d(TAG, "looping");
            ;
        }
    }
    }
```